# Button inside a box with css,html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i have maded an outerbox which contains an innerbox .The code is

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<body>

<div id="boxed">

<div id="anotherbox"> </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

## the css file

```
#boxed {
  width: 150px;
padding: 50px;
border: 5px solid gray;
margin: 0;
background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}

#boxed:hover > #anotherbox {



 width: 50px;
padding: 40px;
border: 5px solid gray;
margin: 0;


visibility: visible;

}
```

This works fine..

But what i need is that i want to display a simple button inside the inner box.I have tried some javascript code but it dint worked out.

Hope you guys can help me ..P:S ..i dont need a jquery solution..Thanks

Comment: Just use `<button>`? Or is that too easy?

Comment: You can use pure CSS to create a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
#boxed {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}

#boxed:hover > #anotherbox {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxed">
  <div id="anotherbox">
    <input type="button" value="inside" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u tell me why it became inside of the inner column when you used button value as inside ??

Comment: This has nothing to do with the value of the button. It is inside the `anotherbox div` in the HTML, this is what causes it to be inside the inner column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a button, as follows:

The HTML:

```css
#boxed {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
#boxed:hover > #anotherbox {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
#boxed:hover #anotherbox > button {
    width: 16px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxed">
    <div id="anotherbox">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no ..i just want the button inside the inner box./.

Comment: You want it in `#boxed`, not in `#anotherbox`, correct?